# How to Create snowflake table with primary keys and and partition columns ? Sample DDL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need some sample DDL to create a snowflake table with primary keys and partition columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation can sometimes be a little overwhelming, I get it, so here is an example.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE stack_overflow (
    post_id          INTEGER,
    post_str         VARCHAR(20),
    post_timestamp   TIMESTAMP_LTZ,
    PRIMARY KEY (post_id, post_str))
CLUSTER BY (to_date(post_timestamp));
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html